# ApachePOI generates org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I sometimes get the following exception when creating Excel sheets using Apache POI

```
ApachePOI generates org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

It often happens after a fairly simple code addition such as the one below:

```
Row myRow= CellUtil.getRow(1, xlsMainTable);
CellUtil.getCell(myRow, 10).setCellValue(d.getParamStr());
```

Therefore it can not be a problem with libraries not being installed properly.

Comment: What's the full stacktrace? You've sadly missed out the interesting part...

Comment: OK. If (when) this happens again I will try and post it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This often happens to me if there is a null value in the `setCellValue()`

If you prevent `setCellValue` with being fed null values then this problem should go away.